# Which module in the MEAN stack collects mongodb dependencies?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mean-stack

```
>> Error: Cannot find module 'mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/read_preference'
```

I am running a grunt server that can't find mongodb connection read_preference. As a result, my DOM was broken.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it may be an issue with you package.json. Perhaps missing dependencies?

I have also seen this problem with mongoskin. If you are using that, try removing and reinstalling it.

Answer (score 0):

After running `npm install`, you get `node_modules` directory populated with all dependencies. Here is what I got for default MEAN distribution:

```
$ find . -name "read_preference*" -print
./node_modules/connect-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/read_preference.js
./node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/read_preference.js
```

And in `package.json` you can see following related entries:

```
"connect-mongo": "~0.4.1",
"mongoose": "~3.8.8",
```

Which are the modules you need to have to resolve that dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the node_modules directory and run `npm install`.